# css takes forever to load

Tags: php, html

here's what i have :

file structure:

[image: file structure]

Here is link to css from view/_templates/header.php

[image: css link]

Here's my config.php in the config folder:

[image: config.php]

If i echo out URL i get the following:

`http://localhost:8080/mini/`

This is what ive done:

I have change the path to css:

[image: css path]

`HERE IS THE MAIN PROBLEM`:

When i changed the css path it only worked once. If i make any changes to my style sheet, then the page style does not get updated immediately, If i refresh the page after about a minute , the new styles is then appled.

I use Ubuntu 14.04, dont know if that is relevant or not.

Comment: You have to clear your browser cache (or add some always changing parameter to url, like random number or timestamp, to force browser always to reload the CSS)

Comment: @Darhazer I just cleared my cache, still not working